# Ruby access nested attributes with symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I'm trying to write a method that takes **an object**, **a symbol** (or something else, here's the question) and "upcases" the value at the key (for example).

**Simple** case:

```
foo = { a: 'hi', b: 'there' }

def upc_value(object, key)
  object[key].upcase!
end

upc_value(foo, :b)

puts foo #=> { a: 'hi', b: 'THERE' }
```

But I also want the method to work with nested attributes if my `foo` object is more complex.

**More complex** case:

```
foo = { a: 'hi', b: [{ c: 'foo', d: 'bar' }, { c: 'bob', d: 'lisa' }] }

def upc_value(object, key)
  object[key].upcase!
end

# I would like to be able to do something like:   

upc_value(foo, :b[:d])

puts foo #=> { a: 'hi', b: [{ c: 'foo', d: 'BAR' }, { c: 'bob', d: 'LISA' }] }
```

I obviously can't do this and I'm curious if something like a "deep_symbol" exists...

---

**REAL PROBLEM:**
The real thing I'm trying to achieve here is a module that removes the host from every field that contains a URL before a model is saved.
It's included in every model that needs it and I call a `fields_containing_url` method that takes the symbols of the fields.
The problem is that I have nested attributes on one of my models and I need to access them with the very same method that takes symbols...

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start. It's a recursive method changing your data in place :

```
def deep_transform(object, key, &block)
  case object
  when Array
    object.each do |element|
      deep_transform(element, key, &block)
    end
  when Hash
    object.each_value do |value|
      deep_transform(value, key, &block)
    end
    if value = object[key]
      object[key] = yield(value)
    end
  end
end

foo = { a: 'hi', b: 'there' }
deep_transform(foo, :b){ |str| str.upcase }
p foo
# {:a=>"hi", :b=>"THERE"}

foo = { a: 'hi', b: [{ c: 'foo', d: 'bar' }, { c: 'bob', d: 'lisa' }] }
deep_transform(foo, :d, &:upcase) # Alternative way to call the method
p foo
# {:a=>"hi", :b=>[{:c=>"foo", :d=>"BAR"}, {:c=>"bob", :d=>"LISA"}]}
```

Note that the method will mutate every value related to a `:d` key. You don't specify `:b[:d]` as in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it works like a charm!
I just added a case to the switch statement to fit my needs: 
  when MyModel
    object.attributes.each_value do |value|
      deep_transform(value, key, &block)
    end
  end